# Copy To... broken with IOS 13

Tags: swift, email, attachment, xcode11

Before upgrading to iOS13 on my device I was able to copy an attached email plist file to my app.
Now my app no longer shows up in the "Copy To" list in the email.

Here's the method used for the app's plist file:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work for me. For the file type I just made an abitrary extension to the file I was saving as an email attachment:  filename.anyuniqueextension

Under Document Types I left the default value of "Damian-s.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}"

Then under "UTTypeTagSpecification" change Item 0 to "anyuniqueextension"

Make sure in your app that you read and write the file extension with "anyuniqueextension"

All of my file types are .plist.